# Google Analytics API - long term access token via server

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I'm setting up a stats part for a web application that will access Google Analytics API always on our own app ID (all the stats are stored in our own Google Analytics, not the customer's Analytics).

I'm trying to automatise the token handling mechanism, and have so far managed to setup code that will get an original access_token alongside a refresh_token.

The issue here is pretty straightforward: the access_token is only valid 60min, and the refresh_token can be used once.

As we are trying to access our own data via a web app, I'd suppose there exists some kind of private access token that can be used for all requests, but I can't seem to find anything that fits these needs. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Refresh token can be used more than once.  see: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if you want to answer straight up to the question I'll accept it ! Thanks.